# WinRT - no static constructors?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I'm currently authoring some WinRT custom controls in c++, and my compiler/intellisense is telling me that static constructors are not allowed.

I need to set up some static data, and I could use a private bool instance flag and on the first instantiation of my class I can create the static data etc.. (effectively achieving the same thing).

However, maybe I've missed something, as this seems a bit long-winded.

What is the canonical alternative approach to static construction in WinRT/c++

Thanks

Comment: None of this is WinRT-specific, is it? You're simply asking how to initialize static data in C++? Can you give an example? Why do you need a static constructor to initialize it? Why not just... initialize it?

Comment: As a c# developer, im used to using static constructors, and I assumed there was an equivalent in c++ - but yes, I just need to instantiate and initialize static data

Comment: @DeanChalk I don't think C++ has such a concept as a static constructor. I can't see why a normal constructor wouldn't do the job you require. Why not post some relevant code. You probably just making some simple error.

Comment: @jalf In fact I guess it is not a C++ question, but a C++/CX question (and therefore somehow WinRT specific), but I'm not sure, as either the OP is not aware of the difference or he indeed uses standard C++ with WinRT using the WRL. And C++/CX might indeed have static constructors, considering the many other .NETisms it has (though from the question is seems not to).

Comment: @john Well, a normal constructor won't do the job, since it is run for each object and not once for each class. But in fact a simple static initialization (like in *Joachim*'s answer) will do, too.

Comment: C++/CX does not have static constructors. Anyway, an obvious answer would be to "use fewer statics" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare the static members inside the class, but you have to define them outside:

```
// In header file
class Foo
{
    static int bar;
    static int bar2;

    static int init_bar3() { return 123; }
};

// In source file
int Foo::bar;

// Define and intiailize
int Foo::bar2 = 5;

// For more complicated initialization
int Foo::bar3 = Foo::init_bar3();
```

Comment: @DeanChalk See my modified answer.

Comment: @Dean Chalk: You don't have to use a literal to initialize a static - you can use the result of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support static constructors. Most of the time, you should use static initialisation as shown in [Joachim Pileborg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385018/59379). I'd advise you to adapt to that idiomatic C++ way of performing static initialisation rather than trying to write C++ in a C# style.

However, if you really need a C# style static constructor in C++, you can fake them:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() {
    static_constructor();//call must appear in every constructor
  }

  Foo(Bar bar, Baz baz) {
    static_constructor();//call must appear in every constructor
  }

private:    
  static void static_constructor() {
    static bool run = false;
    if( !run ) {
      run = true;
      //your logic goes here
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As Joachim Pileborg demonstrates in his answer, a global variable can have a dynamic initializer, which can be used as a form of "static constructor" in C++ and C++/CX.  Note that you can use a lambda expression to to keep the initialization local, e.g.

```
int Foo::bar = [](){ return 123; }();
```

However, you would be well advised not to do this, if possible, for two reasons.  First, the order in which global variables are dynamically initialized is only partially specified.  If you have a dynamic initializer that depends on other global variables defined in another source file, you are likely to run into trouble.

Second, and more importantly, a Windows Runtime component is a DLL, and dynamic initialization of global variables occurs as part of DLL initialization, which happens when the DLL's entry point is called.  As MSDN notes in the documentation of [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583.aspx), "There are serious limits on what you can do in a DLL entry point."  If you search the internet for "DllMain" you will find many resources describing the problems that can arise from doing anything exciting during DLL initialization.

Notably, you are prohibited from doing anything that might cause another DLL to be loaded.  This means that, generally, you cannot use--directly or indirectly--any Windows Runtime types that are not defined in your DLL because the DLL(s) in which they are defined may not yet have been loaded.  I've debugged several hangs that resulted from deadlocks caused by exotic work done during dynamic initialization.

So, as an alternative, encapsulate global variables in a function...

```
class Foo {
public:
    static int bar() {
        static int value = [](){ return 123; }();
        return value;
    }
};
```

...and use `Foo::bar()` instead of `Foo::bar`.  Block-scope static variables are initialized once, when the function is first entered.  Note that if you use `Foo::bar` from multiple threads you may need to synchronize the initialization; C++11 requires that the initialization be thread-safe, but Visual C++ does not yet (as of Visual C++ 2012) support this feature of C++11.